# Get the files whose date in the filename is greater than some specific date using Powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I have a specific date "2021/11/28", i want the list of files from example filenames(below) whose file name is greater than 2021/11/28. remember not the creation time of the file names.

```
 "test_20211122_aba.*"
 "abc_20211129_efg.*"
 "hij_20211112_lmn.*" 
 "opq_20211130_rst.*"
```

I'm expecting to get

```
 "abc_20211129_efg.*"
 "opq_20211130_rst.*"
```

Really appreciate your help.

Comment: Will they all have `test_` at the start?

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have edited the files names as they all are unique. I tried this code but it's not working. $_.BaseName -match '\d{4}_\d{2}_\d{2}' -and [datetime]::ParseExact(([regex]::Match($_.BaseName,'\d{4}\d{2}\d{2}').Value),'yyyy_MM_dd',$null) -gt "2021_11_28" }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't strictly need to parse your strings into dates (`[datetime]` instances): Because the date *strings* embedded in your file names are in a format where their *lexical* sorting is equivalent to *chronological* sorting, you can compare the string representations directly:

```
# Simulate output from a Get-ChildItem call.
$files = [System.IO.FileInfo[]] (
  "test_20211122_aba1.txt",
  "abc_20211129_efg2.txt",
  "hij_20211112_lmn3.txt",
  "hij_20211112_lmn4.txt",
  "opq_20211130_rst5.txt"
)

# Filter the array of files.
$resultFiles = 
  $files | Where-Object {
    $_.Name -match '(?:^|.*\D)(\d{8})(?:\D.*|$)' -and
      $Matches[1] -gt ('2021/11/28"' -replace '/')
   }

# Print the names of the filtered files.
$resultFiles.Name
```

- `$_.Name -match '(?:^|.*\D)(\d{8})(?:\D.*|$)'` looks for (the last) run of exactly 8 digits in each file name via a capture group (`(...)`), reflected in the automatic `$Matches` variable's entry with index `1` (`$Matches[1]`) afterwards, if found.
- `'2021/11/28"' -replace '/'` removes all `/` characters from the input string, to make the format of the date strings the same. For brevity, the solution above performs this replacement *in each loop operation*. In practice, you would perform it *once*, before the loop, and assign the result to a variable for use inside the loop.

Comment: sure, i will soon. Somehow I couldn't see my previous comment. Commenting again " Awesome! Your code worked like a charm. Thanks a ton"

Comment: Could you pls help. I'm working on other script which requires to compare the same with today's date. Something like this..but i'm getting formatting issue. `Where-Object {$_.Name -match '(?:^|.*\D)(\d{8})(?:\D.*|$)' -and $Matches[1] -eq (Get-Date).Date}`

Comment: @Razz, replace `(Get-Date).Date` with `(Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')`. If you need further help, please create a new question post.